# Plist with Auto fill option like info plist

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, plist

I am in developing a ios library in which I plan to read some data from a plist in application bundle. The plist must need to contain only a fixed set of keys that I need to process. How can I create a plist which allow only a fixed set of keys like info plist.

[image: Sample info plist with key selection]

See the info plist allow the developer only to add a fixed set of keys they needed. How can I create a plist with this option.

thanks,
Naveen Shan